# How to know if Mosque is Shia or Sunni?

Tags: nikah, sunni, shiism, masjid

I was researching to find some mosques in an area/state and came across one that provides Nikah services.

When reading their document in terms of a Marriage contract, it had the word Shi'a in it and it made me wonder if the marriage contract/process is not a sunni process.

how does one know if the marriage contract AND the mosque is of a sunni or shia sect?

I quote from their marriage contract document:

"...Shi’a Ithna-Asheri (Ja’fari) laws of Islam..."

It seems difficult to find a mosque who can perform a straight forward sunni Nikah. Does anyone know in the state of Washington or Portland if there sunni mosques who can perform interfaith marriages?

Comment: This post should help http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5/whats-the-difference-between-a-sunni-and-shiite-mosque however one still can discuss some answers. The best way anyhow is to ask most mosques -at least in Europe- have phone!

Comment: Thanks. The thing is you don't want to be rude/offensive by phoning up and asking if they are a Shia mosque or a sunni mosque - nor do you want a shia nikah if you are a sunni etc...

Comment: I don't think that this is offensiv or would be regarded as such.

Answer (score 2):

How do we know if the mosque is Shiite or Sunni?
You can ask the Imam of the mosque because all the mosques in the world are not very different from each other with external or internal differences. Therefore, there is no difference when comparing Shiite and Sunni mosques, except for the differences in their beliefs and customs.
Although Shiites and Sunnis are Muslims of different religions, Shiites are allowed to pray in Sunni mosques and vice versa.

Ref: https://fa.mldunbound.org/contrast/difference-between-shia-and-sunni-mosques-af137b/

Answer (score 1):

Ask the Imam of the mosque if it is a Sunni or a Shia mosque. There are many mosques in both Washington and Portland. Search Google for "mosque in Washington Portland". You will get many results.

[image]

Comment: yes maybe so but some of them are NOT sunni mosques. and actually there aren't many either as I have found. For instance there is a mosque in Portland that is of the ahmadiyyaa school of thought.